# Extract Float from Specific String Using Regular Expression

Tags: regex

What regular expression do I use to extract, for example, 1.09487 from the following text contained in a .txt file?  Also, how would I modify the regular expression to account for the case where the float is negative (for example, -1.948)?

I tried several suggestions on Google as well as a regular expression generator, but none seem to work.  It seems I want to use an anchor (such as ^) to start searching for digits at the word "serial" and then stop at "(", but this doesn't seem to work.

Output in .txt file:

Entropy = 7.980627 bits per character.

```
Optimum compression would reduce the size
of this 51768 character file by 0 percent.

Chi square distribution for 51768 samples is 1542.26, and randomly
would exceed this value less than 0.01 percent of the times.

Arithmetic mean value of data bytes is 125.93 (127.5 = random).
Monte Carlo value for Pi is 3.169834647 (error 0.90 percent).
Serial correlation coefficient is 1.09487 (totally uncorrelated = 0.0).
```

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Would you mind sharing the regular expressions you tried and what result they gave you? Also, what programming language are you using? And one more question: is the last number (`1.09487`) the only one you want?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be sufficient:

```
(?<=Serial correlation coefficient is )[-\d.]+
```

Unless you're expecting garbage, this will work fine.

Comment: This worked perfectly.  Apparently you knew what I was asking :)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
(-?\d+\.\d+)(?=\s\(totally)
```

check [here](http://regex101.com/r/eX5fD5)

Comment: I don't think you can depend on `totally`. If there is any correlation, it will probably use a different word.